# Как обновить роль пользователя через Wordpress REST API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wordpress, api, rest

Я ищу способ обновить данные уже зарегистрированных пользователей на моем сайте через API. Требуется менять роль и членство.
На скриншоте сверху видим 2 пользователя с нужными ролями и членством. 2 пользователя снизу - нужно исправить.

[image: Скриншот панели управления сайтом]

Пытаюсь на Python 3 посылать запрос так:

```
import base64
import requests

url = 'http://mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/18'
my_data = 'login:password'  #admin

# Standard Base64 Encoding
encodedBytes = base64.b64encode(my_data.encode("utf-8"))
encodedStr = str(encodedBytes, "utf-8")

data = {'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % encodedStr}
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
print(response.text)
```

Но получаю ошибку:

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

В wordpress использую плагин:

[image: Скриншот плагина]

Моя цель: создать закрытую страницу с записями на сайте, которую могут читать только те пользователи, которые оплатили подписку на сайте. Оплата этой подписки (товара) происходит через WooCommerce.
Подскажите, что тут можно сделать и какой выход найти? Возможно использовать другой плагин или что-то еще.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#update-a-user

Comment: а в чем проблема написать свой роут ?

Comment: Не понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду. Приведите пример. Если это решит мою проблему, то я отмечу ответ

Answer (score 0):

Регаем свой маршрут и внутри колбека обновляем роль (не забываюем про логин/пароль или ключ или nonce или другой способ авторизации):

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_rest_route' );
function register_rest_route(
            $this->namespace,
            '/update_user_role',
            array(
                'methods'  => 'POST',
                'args'     => array(
                    'user_id' => array(
                        'type'     => 'integer',
                        'required' => true,
                    ),
                ),
                'callback' => array( $this, 'update_user_role' ),
            )
        );
function update_user_role( \WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    $user_id = $request->get_param( 'user_id' )

    $args = arrray(
        'ID' => $user_id,
        'role'   => 'Ваша роль',
    );
    wp_update_user( $args );
}
```